# Synology cifs mount wont allow execution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, server-message-block, cifs

I have a synology NAS. I am able to mount a cifs directory fine on linux (tried both centos 6 and Ubuntu 12). I can do everything fine except I can't execute anything on it. If I try tab to complete, it doesn't show any executables, only directories. If I actually type the executable, it says "permission denied" even if I try it as root.

My fstab looks like this:

```
//172.22.1.3/public/data /data cifs user,uid=501,rw,suid,credentials=/etc/credentials 0 0 auto
```

Am I doing something wrong on the linux side? Or is this a synology or NAS in general problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but have you set the execute permission on the file(s) for either the user/group you using?

Comment: Rex, thanks for stating the obvious, you never know! Yes, for example the "configure" file, when I do "ls -a" gives  -rwxrwxrwx  1 ivan users 499143 Aug  2 17:36 configure

Comment: What is strange is the mapping of who I am on linux, and who has permissions on the synology.

Comment: In fact, even trying to load a library that has been set in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives an error. This used to work. Confused.

Comment: how do you type the executable? do you use full or relative path to it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really old question but I found it trying to resolve the same issue. I think I have found the solution (at least it worked for me).

I found that if I remove the "user" option the problem goes away. Or, if I use "user,exec" in place of just "user".

I finally found at the bottom on one version of the man page:

```
user   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the
          mounting user is written to the mtab file  (or  to  the  private
          libmount  file  in /run/mount on systems without a regular mtab)
          so that this same user can unmount the filesystem  again.   This
          option  implies  the  options  noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless
          overridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option   line
          user,exec,dev,suid).
```